# MaskedTextBox Currency Input Mask Limits

Tags: c#, winforms, currency, mask

Im trying to make a `Custom Input Mask` for `currency` in `Visual Studio 2013`

[image]

But, this type of mask has a limit: **9999,00**. 
I can't write numbers like **99999999,00**.
I want a `mask` that works with any amount of numbers
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of applying the mask via Regular Expresions is detailed in Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234064.aspx Pertinent to your case it could be something like: `$\d{9}.00` Hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Instead of creating a custom mask, create a custom maskedTextbox.

Even with the correct mask, the delivered maskedTextBox is difficult for users to enter data. The currencyTextbox automatically formats/shifts the entered values.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/irenak/2006/03/21/sysk-87-a-better-maskedtextbox-for-currency-fields/

Once you add that class to your project, you'll see the currencyTextBox appear in your toolbox. Then just set a mask for it depending on how large a dollar value you want to store. According to the author, you use all 0s, I personally used "$000,000.00"

Comment: Actually I found something I liked even better.  Do not use TextBox for input numbers. Use the NumericUpDown. Set your commas and decimals right there in the properties.

Answer (score -3):

```
//Crie um textbox com o name txt_valor e atribua os eventos KeyPress,KeyUp e 
// Leave e uma string valor;
string valor;
    private void txt_valor_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == ',')
            {
                e.Handled = (txt_valor.Text.Contains(","));
            }
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }            
    }

    private void txt_valor_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        valor = txt_valor.Text.Replace("R$", "");
        txt_valor.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDouble(valor));
    }

    private void txt_valor_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        valor = txt_valor.Text.Replace("R$","").Replace(",","").Replace(" ","").Replace("00,","");
        if(valor.Length == 0)
        {
            txt_valor.Text = "0,00"+valor;
        }
        if(valor.Length == 1)
        {
            txt_valor.Text = "0,0"+valor;
        }
        if(valor.Length == 2)
        {
            txt_valor.Text = "0,"+valor;
        }
        else if(valor.Length >= 3)
        {
            if(txt_valor.Text.StartsWith("0,"))
            {
                txt_valor.Text = valor.Insert(valor.Length - 2,",").Replace("0,","");
            }
            else if(txt_valor.Text.Contains("00,"))
            {
                txt_valor.Text = valor.Insert(valor.Length - 2,",").Replace("00,","");
            }
            else
            {
                txt_valor.Text = valor.Insert(valor.Length - 2,",");
            }
        }           
        valor = txt_valor.Text;
        txt_valor.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDouble(valor));
        txt_valor.Select(txt_valor.Text.Length,0);
    }
```

Comment: With this code, you will have the mascara of monetary value and execution time.